# Read json and upload to mongo db getting error - ObjectParameterError: Parameter "obj" to Document() must be an object,

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a json data in a variable

```
 let records =    {
       "Name":"Stephen",
       "Age":10,
       "School":"PSB"
    },
    {
       "Name":"Rocky",
       "Age":09,
       "School":"BSR"
    },
    {
       "Name":"Emy",
       "Age":15,
```

Created a Schema with mongoose named post.js

```
    const mongoose = require("mongoose")
    
    const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        Name:String,
        Age:Number,
        School:String,
    })

const Post = mongoose.model("Post",postSchema)
module.export = Post
```

Now, how can I update the database

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")

const Post = require("./database/models/Post")
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/node-js-blog")

Post.create({
JSON.parse(records)
})
```

But it thrown error.

So could you please help me on how to pass this json data to the table collections ?

I am getting error :

```
ObjectParameterError: Parameter "obj" to Document() must be an object,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to pass [an array](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.create) to `Model.create`. So instead of wrapping the array in an object, you can simply do:

```
await Post.create(JSON.parse(records));
```

Also note the `JSON.parse` is only necessary if `records` is e.g. a json-string. If it's already an array you can pass it directly:

```
 let records =    [{
       "Name":"Stephen",
       "Age":10,
       "School":"PSB"
    },
    {
       "Name":"Rocky",
       "Age":09,
       "School":"BSR"
    }];

await Post.create(records);
```

Comment: Got an error - ObjectParameterError: Parameter "obj" to Document() must be an object. could you please help

Comment: Are you actually passing the `records` array as I do in my answer?